# How to get a list of java restful GET/POST methods?

Tags: java, rest

How to get a list of java restful GET/POST methods to put on html page for example ?

Comment: Can you provide more details of you wish to achieve?

Comment: What technologies does the REST service use? Is this a service you have control over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about an automatic way to get a list of resources and supported methods? That's going to depend on how the server-side RESTful interface was implemented. The interface may have a Web Application Description Language ([WADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)) document that describes the resources and methods in a machine-readable format. One could write client-side code that consumes the document and presents the model as HTML. WADLs aren't widely supported, but some frameworks like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html) can be configured to generate them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your service was written in Java (from the way you've tagged your question), I'd recommend you use [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) to document your REST endpoints.